# Wifi not working in Ubuntu 16.04 LTS (Using Realtek RTL8723BE Wireless Network Adapter)

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, hp, realtek

I've visited each and every thread on the topic and tried every solution available over the last two days, including using ethernet to import the drivers from GitHub, but my Laptop refuses to recognize any and all wireless connections around. I've looked up the drivers on the Realtek website as well, but it's like the card doesn't exist. I can use a terminal pretty well, so all solutions are welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Read this complete answer: http://askubuntu.com/a/60395/496493

Comment: @Woeitg How are Broadcom drivers related?

Comment: You may need to use the [wireless script](http://askubuntu.com/a/425205/175814) and edit your question to add results to help us find a solution to the problem

Answer (score 0):

In a terminal window (Ctrl-Alt-t) enter: sudo lshw
and your password when asked.
Search the output for:

*-network

```
   description: Wireless interface
```

Write down on paper the logical name, and the serial number (six double digits, separated by colons).

On your task bar, select the network Edit connections. Enter your wireless connection name. For ssid: re-enter the connection name. For Mode: enter client. For BSSID: leave it blank. For Device: enter the logical name you copied down from the network description. For Cloned MAC address: enter the six double digits, separated by colons you wrote down.
For MTU: select automatic.

On the Security page, select WPA & WPA2 Personal. Enter your wireless connection password. For IPv4: select Automatic (DHCP). For IPv6: select Automatic. Save the connection definition.

In the terminal window, enter:  systemctl restart NetworkManager

Hopefully your network should now be working.